# Build android app with kivy but meet a error

Tags: android, kivy

i have try to build android app by kivy framework , and using kivy provide vm,build have many bug , any can help ,thanks. Some new updated

```
[INFO]:    -> running cp -a python-install/lib private
       working:Traceback (most recent call last):/pyth...(and 946 more) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/FB/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 766, in <module>
main()
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/FB/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 763, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/FB/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 344, in __init__
getattr(self, command_method_name)(unknown)
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/FB/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 93, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, dist_args)
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/FB/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 140, in build_dist_from_args
ctx.bootstrap.run_distribute()
File "pythonforandroid/bootstraps/sdl2/__init__.py", line 58, in run_distribute
File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 173, in shprint
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 565, in next
self.wait()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 500, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
```

sh.ErrorReturnCode_1

```
RAN: '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android
```

list'

```
STDOUT:
SWT folder '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-     20/tools/lib/OpenJDK
```

64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
    2033

```
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

x86_64' does not exist.Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.


STDERR:

# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always
--storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/FB/.buildozer/android/platform/build
create --dist_name=FB --bootstrap=sdl2
--requirements=kivy,paramiko,pycrypto,ecdsa --arch armeabi-v7a
--copy-libs
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install colorama version 0.3.3 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i have try to update colorama to 0.3.3 , it fixed previous error , but have new error occur , i have updated the post,thx

Comment: Are you running in a VM? The error seems to suggest it's just run out of space.